# ADMIN0011: InvalidRequestFault When adding 2nd ADFS Server

Tags: microsoft-office-365, adfs

We have a multi forest single tenancy Office 365 environment, many federated domains. When I try and add a second ADFS server during the configuration step I receive the error ADMIN0011: InvalidRequestFault.

The only reference I have found online is http://blog.ryanbetts.co.uk/2015/12/adfs-server-farm-join-fails-with.html but we dont seem to have duplicates like suggested in that example.

The only thing I am aware of is we did need to modify Office 365 claim rule to handle multi forest, and we appear to have two rules that have no title.

Everyone I have contacted is stumped - was hoping someone may have come across this before?

Comment: You need to gather AD FS debug logs in order to get more insight into whats occurring. There are many possibilities as to what is happening here. Please raise a support ticket with Microsoft via the O365 portal to get some technical assistance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this issue standard Office 365 support would not assist, after I opened a ticket under EA/MSDN, the outcome was:

**Symptom**:  Unable to add ADFS server to WID based farm, error ADMIN0011: InvalidRequestFault. Confirmed there are no duplicate policy usage type in any relay trust's (ref http://blog.ryanbetts.co.uk/2015/12/adfs-server-farm-join-fails-with.html).

**Reason**: Joining ADFS Servers C:\WINDOWS\ADFS\MICROSOFT.IDENTITYSERVER.DKM.DLL not 6.3.9600.17564 or above.

**Resolution**: Install KB29119355 or apply hotfix https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3020773/time-out-failures-after-initial-deployment-of-device-registration-serv.